# Get parent repeater from child repeater

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing out a list of links broken down into Year and Month like so :

```
<ul>
  <li>2012</li>
  <ul>
    <li>July (12)</li>
    <li>June (8)<li>
    (etc)
  </ul>
  <li>2011</li>
    <li>July (7)</li>
    (etc)
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am using two Repeaters, one for Years ("repYears") and a nested Repeater for Months ("repMonths").  During the ItemDataBound event for repYears, I databind repMonths.  The data comes from a Generic List of these objects:

```
public class ArchiveItem
{
    public ArchiveItem(long Id, string Month, int Year)
    {
        PostId = Id;
        Month = Month;
        Year = Year;
    }

    public long PostId { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

So far I am successfully writing out the years and months.

What I need to do next is calculate the number of items per month (i.e. populate the number in the brackets from the HTML above).

To do this (during repMonths_ItemDataBound()) I need to know what year the repYears Repeater is currently on.  That will give me the current month and current year from which I can then work out the count.

I can access the current month easily as I am within ItemDataBound so I can use e.Item.DataItem.

So how can I access the current DataItem value from the parent Repeater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if i get the point since you haven't shown code.

If you are in the child repeater's `ItemDataBound` and you need to get a reference to the parent item's `DataItem`, you can use the `NamingContainer` property:

in `ItemDataBound` of the child-repeater:

```
var repeater = (Repeater)sender;
var parentItem = (RepeaterItem)repeater.NamingContainer;
var parentDataItem = parentItem.DataItem;
```

Comment: Thank you thats exactly it.  The NamingContainer was the missing piece of the puzzle!  I will accept as soon as the button lets me click it.